# BJT common collector amplifier with a voltage gain sligthly higher than one

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, common-collector

How could I explain why a common collector amplifier has a voltage gain higher than one ? In a lab session, I built this circuit :

[image: Common collector amplifier circuit]

With Vg=30 mVpp and Vcc=15V, students were asked to give the voltage gain of the circuit in function of frequency. In class, we derived the small-signal equivalent circuit and concluded that the voltage gain must be sligthly lower than one. Well, I was pretty confused today because the mid-band voltage gain is roughly 1.15.

As the teacher always says, it doesn't matter if the experimental data don't fit with the expected values given by the small-signal model, but we must be able to explain the differences between theory and our observations. The thing is, I'm out of words. It seems to me that it is impossible to have a gain higher than one, Ve must be lower than Vin.

If you have an idea, even only an hypothesis, any help is welcome.

Values related to the circuit :

Rg=1K

R1=22k

R2=10k

R3=1.2K

R4=500

Ccc=100u

C1=C2=10u

Vcc=15V

Vg=30 mVpp

Comment: You need to provide resistor values.

Comment: Of course, I totally forgot to mention!

Comment: And why are the voltage, resistor and capacitor values not on the schematic?

Comment: @EthanB. Did you make rms or pk-pk measurements?

Comment: One possibility is yours”mid-band” is around 20 MHz where 10:1 probe ground that’s too long, causes resonance gain.  In any answer the correct answer is calibration or reactive resonant gain not shown in schematic.

Comment: Resonances involving the Ccc cap, or long leads, etc.

Comment: Exactly how did you measure your gain? Add the schematic of the probe to that of the circuit. It's almost certainly interactions of probe and circuit.

Comment: The measurements were made with an oscilloscope (Tektronix TDS3012C). I measured peak-to-peak voltage using 1MΩ probes at Vin and Vout. I even simulated the effect of theses probes using PSPICE, but the gain is still less than one.

Comment: I would add the schematic of the probes, but for the moment I don't know the exact model I used, so I don't know its specifications (like its capacitance for instance).

Comment: Pk-Pk is not an appropriate measurement technique for low level measurements. Any noise or EM trash adds directly to the Pk-Pk measurement. Contrast that to RMS where each signal source adds geometrically. Try it in spice stack 3 voltage sources in series, compare the RMS output to Pk-Pk output.

Comment: @sstobbe I went to the lab yesterday and measured the gain with RMS voltage. I got a 0.98 instead of the 1.15 obtained with Pk-Pk. As you said, Pk-Pk considers the minimum and maximum of the signal (including the noise) and since I am working at low amplitudes, noise matters.

Comment: @EthanB. Glad to hear. An FFT offers even higher selectivity of the signal versus noise, but not all scopes have this feature. Your intuition that something isn't right here will serve you well. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the equations governing your circuit are:

V_R1 = R1 × I_R1

Vb = R2 × I_R2

V_R1 + Vb = Vcc

I_R2 + Ib = I_R1 + I_in

Solving that first group gives:

Vb = (R2 × Vcc + (I_in- Ib) R1 R2 ) / (R1 + R2)

moving on to the rest of the circuit

Vc = Vcc - Ic × R3

Ve = Ie × R4

Ic = hfe × Ib

Ie = Ic + Ib

Ve = Vb - 0.7

Solving that lot I get

Ve = ((1+hfe) R4 (I_in × R1 × R2 - (R1 + R2) × Vbe + R2 × Vcc)) / (R1 × R2 + (1 + hfe)(R1 + R2) R4)

Plugging in your values and solving for steady state (I_in=0)

R1->22000, R2->10000, R3->1200, R4->500, Vbe -> 0.7 , Vcc -> 15, hfe->100

gives:

Ib=69uA, Ic=6.9mA, Ie=7 mA, Vb= 4.2V, Vc = 6.7V and Ve=3.5 V

Those all look plausible and the transistor isn't in saturation,
solving for I_in = (Vg - Vb) / Rg and taking deltas to get the
high frequency limit I get

ΔVe = 0.86 ΔVg

which presumably tallies with your calculations.

The gain of the circuit doesn't change much with hfe, or the resistor values, so it's unlikely to be that.

My guess would be that there was a problem with your experimental set-up. The input impedance of this circuit is much higher than the output impedance, and you're dealing with exceedingly small signals (~10mV RMS). At those values you'll have to take a great deal of care that your measurements are not drowned out by resistance is the ground or power cables. Or indeed that there is no coupling of the output back into the input.

The other obvious posibility is that your input is not well approximated by a voltage source in series with a resistor but by a current source. In that case I_in = Vg/Rg and you get (in the limit)

ΔVe = 6 ΔVg.

Comment: 6x gain with a current source, fascinating.